# Unable to install tensorflow-quantum using pip

Tags: pypi, tensorflow-quantum

Using the command `pip install tensorflow-quantum` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum
```

Not sure why the `versions` is `none`. Also, not sure how to proceed. I can build from source but need help on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using a python version that does not support TensorFlow Quantum.
TensorFlow Quantum is supported on Python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9. Change your Python version to any of these then try reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow-quantum 0.7.2` [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-quantum/0.7.2/#files) for Linux and MacOS, not for w32/w64. And no source code.

You can try to [build from source](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/master/docs/install.md#build-from-source).